# Compute counting variable in dataframe

Tags: r

I have an R data frame:

```
a <- 1:12  
list <- c(rep("x",3),rep("y",4),rep("z",3),rep("x",2))  
data <- data.frame(a,list)

data  
 a list  
 1    x  
 2    x  
 3    x  
 4    y  
 5    y  
 6    y  
 7    y  
 8    z  
 9    z  
10    z  
11    x  
12    x
```

I want to create a new column which begins counting at 1 every time the value of "list" changes, i.e. in this example:

```
b <- c(1:3,1:4,1:3,1:2)    
data <- data.frame(a,list,b)
```

I am far from being an expert in R and cannot for the life of me work out an efficient way of doing this. My main problem seems to be that
any value of "list" can come back at any time, but there is no rule to the length of the blocks of one value.
Does anyone have any ideas? 
Thanks!

Comment: Just a comment: it is often a good idea not to use builtin names (like `data` or `list`) as variable names - if later on you want to use the `list()` function, you may run into very strange errors.

Comment: Indeed, most people would refrain form calling their dog "dog"! for example.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I will keep that in mind from now on.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would use `rle()` to get the run lengths of `list` and then use the handy `sequence()` function to generate the desired counter from the `$lengths` component returned by `rle()`:

```
R> sequence(rle(as.character(data$list))$lengths)
 [1] 1 2 3 1 2 3 4 1 2 3 1 2
```

Notice we have to convert `list` to an atomic vector (character vector in my case) as a factor is not allowed in `rle()`.

To put that into `data`, then wrap this in a call such as

```
data <- transform(data, b = sequence(rle(as.character(list))$lengths))
```

which gives

```
R> data <- transform(data, b = sequence(rle(as.character(list))$lengths))
R> data
    a list b
1   1    x 1
2   2    x 2
3   3    x 3
4   4    y 1
5   5    y 2
6   6    y 3
7   7    y 4
8   8    z 1
9   9    z 2
10 10    z 3
11 11    x 1
12 12    x 2
```

Comment: @user1777393 If you are happy with an Answer please consider accepting one of them. Use the big tick mark next to the Answer you wish to accept. The [ask] section of the [so] faq explains how to do this and why it is helpful/useful to do so.

Answer (score 5):

The key idea is to use `rle()` (run length encoding) on `data$list` (after coercing it to an atomic vector - after all, we are not interested in the specific entries). Then we use `seq()` to create sequences starting at 1 and ending at the calculated run length. Finally, we paste all these sequences together:

```
unlist(lapply(rle(as.numeric(data$list))$lengths,FUN=seq,from=1))
```

Comment: Thank you!! This is exactly what i needed. I didn't know that function, so you have made me very happy.